# Ansible tower job failing within seconds

Tags: ansible-tower

"msg": "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n  setup: Unhandled exception while executing module: The requested object does not exist.
Playbook run took 0 days, 0 hours, 0 minutes, 1 seconds

Comment: I am seeing same error ... my guess is cause is something else and this message is not shedding light on actual error